# How can I access stored values of a Bean from inside another Class

Tags: android, class, arraylist, javabeans

How can I implement this functionality?

```
ApplicationConstants.phoneContacts.add(
  new ContactNumberBean(nameOfContact,
    contactNumber, contactNumberType));
```

ApplicationConstants and ContactNumberBean classes

ContactNumberBean :

```
package com.example.AddressBook;

public class ContactNumberBean 
{
   private String nameOfContact;
   private String contactNumber;  
   private int contactNumberType;

   public String getnameOfContact()
   {
        return nameOfContact;
   }
   public String getcontactNumber()
   {
        return contactNumber;
   }
   public int getcontactNumberType()
   {
        return contactNumberType;
   }
   public ContactNumberBean(String nameOfContact, String contactNumber,int contactNumberType)
   {
       this.nameOfContact=nameOfContact;
       this.contactNumber=contactNumber;
       this.contactNumberType=contactNumberType;
       
   }
}
```

ApplicationConstants :

```
package com.example.AddressBook;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ApplicationConstants
{
    //String[] phoneContacts =new String[10];
    //ArrayList<NameValuePair> list = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    
    /*String s1,s2;
    int i1;
    
    ContactNumberBean cb =new ContactNumberBean(str1,str2,i2);
    
    static ArrayList<String> phoneContacts = new ArrayList<String>();
    phoneContacts.add(s1);
    phoneContacts.add(s2);
    phoneContacts.add(i1);*/

how can implemented in this class functionality ................................
    
**ApplicationConstants.phoneContacts.add(new ContactNumberBean(nameOfContact,
                                        contactNumber, contactNumberType));**
    

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi to access been values in another class create a common class named as Constants.java in that declare and initialize been object like below:

```
public class Constants{

    public static Bean userBeen=new Bean();

}
```

been class:

```
public class Been {

    private string countryName;

    public void setCountry(String s) {
        this.countryName=s;
    } 

    public String getCountry() {
        return countryName;
    }
}
```

set values:

```
public class A{

    String s="India";

    Constants.userBeen.setCountry(s);

    }
}
```

get values:

```
public class B{

    String s=Constants.userBeen.getCountry();

    }

}
```

this will work fine.