# How to start Activity with custom parameters

Tags: android, android-activity, parameters

I need to start an Activity with parameters. I know i can do it with Intents and Bundles, but as far as i know it's only possible with String, boolean, etc...

I have to do it with custom parameters, like user-made classes.

For example, i got PLC-class in main activity, which contains many variables and methods, and i need to use it in the other activity.

I know the "public static" method, but i'm not a fan of it, and i'm sure i can find something else that fits my need.

I hope you guys can help me
Bye

Comment: http://androidhub.wordpress.com/2011/08/03/android-intents-for-passing-data-between-activities-part-3/. example.

Comment: I agree with your opinion on the static method. You might want to consider using fragments instead. I believe, though I'm no pro, that makes it easier to deal with such issues.

Comment: @Squonk It's my class that represents a PLC, tho it contains inputs, ouputs, etc.

Comment: @Arty : You say it is in your main activity...why is it there? Why isn't it in a class file of its own?

Comment: @Squonk My PLC-class is in it's own class file, but i use it in my main activity. PLC-class contains Socket, and i connect this socket in the main activity

Comment: @Arty : So just make your PLC class a singleton.

Comment: @Squonk What do you mean by Singleton ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you can make bean class... which have getter/setter method.. you can set value there, and retrieve those values in any other Activities.Using it class.

E.g

```
public class Constants{

    public static Bean userBeen=new Bean();

}
```

Main activity

```
Constants.userBeen.setValue("anything");
```

In other Activity,, you can get value using userBeenobj;

Other Activity

```
   String s=Constants.userBeen.getValue();
```

Hope this helps to you. I mostly use this.!

Comment: RowItem doesn't exit, do i have to write it myself ?

Comment: :) It is your Bean Class so you can name it as you want. Make your own Class.

Comment: New--> Class ---> Name your class as you want, define variable names..as per your requirment.. right click--> source---> generate getter/setter method--> ok -->finish.

Comment: Can you tell me more about Bean Classes, android is kinda new for me

Comment: I have give you an Example How you use your Class which type is bean

Comment: lol..I have this error   
Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?

Comment: I created a Bean class, but Bean.getValue(); gives me null, and i think it's normal because i just created a new one in a different class

Comment: OK....Have you Ever  heard about SharedPreferences? If it is difficult for you you can use Shared Prefernce,

Comment: i did exactly like you : Bean b = new Bean(); b.getValue(); gives me null. I don't get how your variable b on the 2nd activity can access the one in first activity.

Comment: Hey One more thing..Sorry.. You have to pass rowItem Object through Bundle.. in other Activty,, Dont make new Object in new Activty.It gives you nullpointer

Comment: yeah.. soory. thts my mistake.. :) You

Comment: But you can't pass your Bean object to a Bundle, no method putObject

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355142/how-can-i-access-stored-values-of-a-bean-from-inside-another-class

Comment: I already use Shared Preferences in my app, but it doesn't fit this time, but thanks for your time bud, you really helped me !

Answer (score 1):

Or you can make your class implementing parcelable interface, and put it in a parcel that you send from your source activity to destination activity..

Answer (score 0):

make your custom made class serializable and then put it in bundle like this

```
bundle.putSerializable(key, value);
```

Comment: That will give OP a copy; no?

Comment: @Onur A. I kinda agree with BobbyDigital, i don't want a copy, but the original one

Comment: @Arty: Depending on your design and such, as I said, you might consider looking into a fragment. Fragments can access the activities data directly via `getActivity()`. Or that's the way I understand it.

Comment: @Arty you cannot just pass a reference to your class instance

Comment: I already use Fragments, to display PLC values (like Lights, Temperatures, etc, actually it's an app for house automation), but i don't want this activity to be displayed like the others with right scrolling

Comment: hımm how about parcelable ? and you said you dont want public static but you accept Bean class answer which contains static methods?